# Maven compilation dies with "Killed"

Tags: java, linux, maven-2, ubuntu

I am running a Maven2 compile of a large Java project on a linux virtual machine
Compilation is failing with the following error "compiled with -X for debugging"

[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  /home/{...}/src/main/java
[DEBUG]  /home/{...}/target/generated-sources/meta
[INFO] Compiling 1377 source files to /home/{...}
Killed
(and I go back to bash prompt immediately)

I figure this could be:

- A linux thing (I checked that my ulimit -Hn is okay, 10000)
- A VM thing (this in on an amazon EC2 ubuntu instance)
- A maven / java thing (Never seen this kind of death, usually just out of memory errors and the like)

Any thoughts to narrow down the culprit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My first guess would be that you're running out of memory, and the kernel is killing the compile process.

Comment: Yup, looks like the work of the (in)famous [OOM Killer](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/).

Comment: Argh! Seems that you are correct. Setting maxmem explicitly as per http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#maxmem seems to have done it. Made a bad assumption that it would default to low

Comment: great thanks! your answer helped me to resolve 'KILL' problem by increasing memory on  limux machine

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking to see if there are other resource limits; e.g. run `ulimit -a`.